# Website hosting moved from internal to external, issues

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, hosting

First I would like to let you know that I've researched this problem and I have seen similar questions on other sites, but I am VERY inexperienced when it comes to things like this so I really don't know where to start and I'm very skeptical about changing things in fear that I might break everything..

Okay so here's the problem. At my work we have an internal and external website. The internal is "new.oursite.com", and the external is simply "www.oursite.com", both of which were hosted here. Recently, they got someone to build a new external site which they are now hosting for us. The problem is that when I type in "www.oursite.com" it directs to the old site, but when someone goes to that link outside of this building they get the new site.

I need to somehow change it so that everything points to the new site, while keeping the internal site as is ( very important ).

Not sure what kind of information you may need to help, but if there's anything you need just let me know !

EDIT:

I know now that our nameservers are 10.0.1.4 (IIS 7) and 8.8.4.4 (Google).

So the next step is to find the DNS Records for www.site.com..

Would anyone be able to know where this would be? Or is it also an internal record that is different for everyone and I have to find it myself ?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

This smacks of DNS. There's a DNS record for `www.oursite.com` in your internal DNS server that's pointing to the internal web server's ip address. You need to change this DNS record to point to the external web server's ip address.

Comment: Okay, but like I said I'm very new to this whole concept so I honestly have no idea where that record would be.. Also you should know that I didn't set up anything here, I've recently taken over the internal website (about 3-4 months ago) and this is the first time I've had to play around with anything like this

Comment: Also if it helps we use Ajenti, and I'm working on an Ubuntu box

Comment: We can't help you figure out your internal infrastructure but I can tell you that this smacks of a DNS problem. Look at your workstation's DNS client settings to figure out the ip address of the DNS server(s) that it's using. Then find those servers. Then log onto one of them and launch the DNS server management console/whatever and have a look at the DNS records. You'll likely find the DNS record for `www.oursite.com` there, and then you can change that record so that it resolves to the external web server's ip address.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll keep looking around. One more thing though I just have to make sure.. In Ajenti there's a section "Network", inside there under eth0 > IPv4 > Address, the IP is the one for the old site. Would changing that affect the internal site as well ? I feel like the solution can't be that easy though ..

Comment: I can't help you with that as I don't know anything about Ajenti. Somewhere the old server ip address is being referenced when you connect to `www.oursite.com`, you need to find where that is and change it.